# C++ polymorphism access derived class fields from base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {};

class Deriv : public Base
{
    public:
        int data;
        Deriv(int data): data(data) {} 
};

int main()
{
    Base *t = new Deriv(2);
    std::cout << t->data << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile it, I'm getting the error:

```
x.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
x.cpp:15:21: error: ‘class Base’ has no member named ‘data’
```

**How can I get access to data field (note that I don't want to use Deriv *t = new Deriv(2))?**

Comment: You have to cast it to the specified type first.

Comment: @AtoMerZ, is that the only way?

Comment: Depends on your requirements. You could do what @tp1 said too. Base has no way of knowing about data. **YOU** have to tell it in one way or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared your pointer to be of type `Base` and the compiler is correct, there is no member `data` in that class. You would need to cast the pointer back up to a `Deriv*` in order to access the member in this way. Why are you making the pointer of type to the base class anyway? This is only usually useful when you have a polymorphic class hierarchy.

You could consider using a virtual function to return the value of this member, but without knowing what your classes and code is trying to achieve it is hard to recommend one way or the other. Based on your small code sample, simply using

```
Deriv *t = new Deriv(2);
```

instead, seems a better choice

Comment: Indeed, I have a polymorphic class hierarchy. I used a small example for my question just to point out my problem. I'll use ((Deriv *) t)->data where I need it.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky Oh I see, that was not obvious from the code. Perhaps the virtual function approach is the way to go in the long term then.

Comment: That data field is specific only for Deriv class. I don't want to make a virtual getter, and force all classes that inherit Base to implement it.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky OK - as long as your code works how you want , that is the most important thing

Comment: When casting in C++, you should prefer the use of one of the C++-style  casts as opposed to the plain C style cast: `static_cast<Deriv*>(t)`

Answer (score 5):

Put this to base class:

```
virtual int get_data() const=0;
```

Then derived class will need to implement it - all data of the all derived classes will go through the interface:

```
class Base
{
    virtual int get_data() const = 0;
};

class Deriv: public Base
{
public:
    int data;
    Deriv(int data): data(data) {} 
    virtual int get_data() const
    { return data; }
};
```

Comment: The standard solution. +1. You should mention that this goes in Base too.

Comment: Maybe base shouldn't have this function. How can this be standard?

Comment: @AtoMerZ It's standard because it avoids class switching and introduces a proper interface.

Comment: @tp1, could you explain a little bit?

Comment: The base interface just needs to be designed so that _all_ derived classes can pass their data through it. Like if Derived2 allows 2 ints, then you already need dynamic array in the Base class.

Comment: @tp1, if I add this line to the Base class, I can't instantiate it: "Base *t = new Deriv(2);" fails.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky You need to implement it in Deriv: `virtual int get_data() const { return data; }`. In other words, in Base you define the interface, but in Deriv you actually implement it. I edited tp1's answer to show the code.

Comment: @NikosC., thanks, I figured it out. For my needs, I'd prefer to use the back-cast to Deriv, rather than implement the getter.

Answer (score 2):

Object `t` has type pointer-to-`Base` and `Base` does not define a `data` member, which is the reason why your code fails to compile. If you know for certain that `t` points to an actual object of type `Deriv` (as is the case with your posted code), you can cast it in order to be able to call `Deriv` members:

```
Deriv* d = static_cast<Deriv*>(t);
std::cout << d->data << std::endl;
```

If you didn't know that `t` points to an actual object of type `Deriv`, you would need to polymorphically downcast it via dynamic_cast and check the return value:

```
Deriv* d = dynamic_cast<Deriv*>(t);
if (d != nullptr)
{
    std::cout << d->data << std::endl;
}
```

In any case, based on the code you posted, you don't really gain anything by declaring `t` as a `Base*` if you're just using it to access a data member defined only by `Deriv`.

Comment: Note that dynamic_cast has a reasonable run time overhead, and sometimes needs compile time flags to be set to work properly in some compilers.